# .htaccess: Redirecting subfolder root for specific request only AND keep parameter

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm struggling to implement a conditional redirect. 
All requests `example.com/app/?s={some string}` (and nothing else) should be redirected to `example.com/?s={some string}`.

I tried many things and looking up StackOverflow. My final draft was this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\/app\/\?s=
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /?  [R=301]
```

But it didn't work :-/  Any ideas?

**UPDATE:**

My approach now is

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\/app\/
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^s=(.*)
RewriteRule (.*) /  [R=301,L]
```

Still not working :D

**UPDATE 2:**

Comment: To clarify, there is no query string? The "parameter" is included as part of the URL-path? (Although your code attempt appears to suggest you are trying to match a _query string_?)

Comment: Thank for the hint. I updated my question, but still not found the answer :D

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "not working"? Incorrect redirect? Error? Nothing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> All requests `example.com/app/s={some string}` should be redirected to `example.com/s={some string}`

You have no `?` in your example URLs, consequently there is no *query string*. `s=` is simply part of the URL-path (it's not strictly a URL parameter). (This does, however, contradict your code sample where you are trying to match a `?` and query string? It is this that I was trying to clarify in comments.)

If `s={some string}` is really part of the URL-path then try the following instead:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^app/(s=.*) /$1 [R=302,L]
```

> **UPDATE:** I forgot the `?` in the exaple above

In that case your first "update" should have worked (depending on where you've put the directives). However, it would be better to write it like this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^s=
RewriteRule ^app/$ / [R=302,L]
```

It's more efficient to check the URL-path in the `RewriteRule` *pattern*, since this is processed first. The query string is passed through by default (no need to *capture* `{some string}`).

Test with 302 (temporary) redirects to avoid caching issues. Change to a 301 (permanent) - if that is the intention - only once you have confirmed it is working OK.

You will need to clear your browser cache before testing.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I forgot the `?` in the exaple above :| Stupid... So your solution dows not apply to `app/?s=(.*)` right?

Comment: No, my initial solution would only work with the example URLs given in your question. I've updated my answer. However, this does mean that your "updated" code sample should have worked? Do you have any other directives in your `.htaccess` file? Make sure you've cleared your browser cache.

Comment: THANK YOU! Worked!

Answer (score 0):

[The documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) tells us:

> Modifying the Query String
>
> By default, the query string is passed through unchanged

However, you  are explicitly setting it to be empty.

Comment: Thank you for the hin, that was right. Also, I did not use `%{QUERY_STRING}` to check the query :)

This would be my next approach. But also did not work:

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\/app\/`
`RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^s=(.*)`
`RewriteRule (.*) /  [R=301,L]`

Do you have another hint for me?